# Using getchar() to see if input is a valid identifier

Tags: c

My program is supposed to analyze an input to see if its an identifier. However whenever I input a legal identifier it says its illegal. What is the problem?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int legal = 0;
    char ch;
    printf("enter:");
    ch = getchar();
    while (ch != "\n") {

        if ((ch >= 'a' && ch <= 'z') || (ch>='0' && ch<='9')||(ch>='A' && ch<='Z')||(ch=='_')) {
             legal = 1;
         }
         else{
             legal =0;
             printf("Illegal");
             break;
         }


        ch = getchar();
    } 

    if (legal == 1) {
        printf("legal");
    }


}
```

Comment: Aren't you getting a warning for `ch != "\n"`? Make sure you've turned on full warnings, e.g. `gcc -Wall`

Comment: `ch` is `char`, `"\n"` is `char*`, you can't compare them.

Comment: You can also use functions `isdigit()` and `isalpha()` to test whether a character is a digit or alphabetic, instead of testing ranges.

Comment: @Barmar And `ch` should be declared as `int`, of course, particularly if you plan on using `is*` without UB.

Answer (score 3):

Remember that `"\n"` and `'\n'` are two entirely different things, the first being `char*` and the second being `char`. Fix that and your code works.

If you enable warnings you get this:

```
getch.cpp:9:15: warning: result of comparison against a string literal is unspecified (use strncmp instead) [-Wstring-compare]
    while (ch != "\n") {
              ^  ~~~~
getch.cpp:9:15: error: comparison between pointer and integer ('int' and 'const char *')
    while (ch != "\n") {
           ~~ ^  ~~~~
1 warning and 1 error generated.
```

A compiler like `clang` will alert you to simple mistakes like this if you ask it to, like with `-Wall`.